# How to set sampling 100% rate for trace log and other telemetry as adaptive sampling

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I have .NET web application that configure auto instrument application insight. Under ApplicationInsights.config there is adaptive sampling configuration

```
<TelemetryProcessors>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
    <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
</Add>
</TelemetryProcessors>
```

I also have trace log listener to application under web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
     <listeners>
       <add name="myAppInsightsListener"type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" />
     </listeners>
   </trace>
 </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

When web application runs with a lot of transaction. I notice some logs are not send to application insight. I think it relate to the adaptive sampling. I want all log need to send to application insight but If I change adaptive sampling to fixed rate to 100 it might impact the other telemetry from auto instrument.

My question is

- How can I configure the application insight to get all trace logs from web application and keep all the other part from auto instrument do the same as adaptive sampling?

  - Do I need to use SDK application insight instead of auto instrument?

Answer (score 0):

> [Adaptive Sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling?tabs=net-core-new#types-of-sampling) is the default sampling when you use the `ASP.NET` SDK.

We can set `Adaptive Sampling` either in `Code` or in `ApplicationInsights.config` file.

***In `ApplicationInsights.config`:***

I have taken references from [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/sampling.md#configuring-adaptive-sampling-for-aspnet-applications) to Configure adaptive sampling.

The configurations which you have done is correct, we can add few more settings.

```cs
<SamplingPercentage>100</SamplingPercentage>
```

> If I change adaptive sampling to fixed rate to 100 it might impact the other telemetry from auto instrument.

Yes, Setting the sampling rate to 100% might increase the cost of `Application Insights` and may impact the performance of the Application.

- For this we can use `<ExcludedTypes>` to exclude few types of data.

***Ex:***  `<ExcludedTypes>PageView;Request</ExcludedTypes>`

To Configure Adaptive Sampling in code, refer this [Configure adaptive sampling in code](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/sampling.md#alternative-configure-adaptive-sampling-in-code).

> Do I need to use SDK application insight instead of auto instrument?

As I have mentioned we can configure Sampling in code as well, which overrides the configuration set in `ApplicationInsights.config`, which is not mandatory.

If we want to customize any of the default settings of Sampling, then it is advised to configure in the Code.

***OR***

If you want to make the configuration in a easy and quick way then configure the sampling in `.config` file itself.

Comment: Sadly links no longer work. Could you update them?